# Primary key for multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, key

I have this MySQL Table, the PRIMARY KEY (ID).

```
ID  | COLOR   | SIZE
====================
| 1 |   RED   | 1  |
| 2 |   RED   | 2  |
| 3 |   RED   | 3  |
| 4 |   GREEN | 1  |
| 5 |   GREEN | 2  |
| 6 |   BLUE  | 1  |
===================
```

When i insert this row for example

```
INSERT INTO `test`(`COLOR`, `SIZE`) VALUES (RED',1);
```

i have a duplicate row 
1, RED, 1
and
7, RED, 1
how to avoid this problem?

Thanks

Comment: add an unique constraints  on color

Comment: @scaisEdge `color` and `size`?

Comment: You need to define ` unique key` for `color` column

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  correct  .. thanks

Comment: exactly why you mean with `how to avoid this problem`? because create an `UNIQUE` constraint will generate an error when trying to insert second `Red,1`, so will protect your db table to have duplicate values, but  so you have to handle those error somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alter table

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
ADD UNIQUE (color, size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you run this empty your table first or remove the duplicate row from your table than run it.

```
ALTER TABLE  `test` ADD UNIQUE (color, size)
```

Comment: I have  tried with
ALTER TABLE 'test
   ADD PRIMARY KEY ( `COLOR`,` size`) ;.
But there is an error.
your solution works. by adding " INSERT IGNORE INTO ".
Thanks